# Flatten Hash with Values of Arrays By Order of Index in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, flatten

I'm trying to find a way to flatten a hash of arrays, such that the order of the elements are in order of index. So 1st element of every array gets picked up, then second, then third, and so on, and if there is no element of that index then move on to the next array instead of returning nil or something.

Example 1: `{a: [1, 2, 3], b: [4, 5], c: [6, 7, 8, 9]}`

Result: `[1, 4, 6, 2, 5, 7, 3, 8, 9]`

Example 2: `{i: ['A'], ii: ['B', 'C', 'D'], iii: ['E'], iv: ['F', 'G]}`

Result: `['A', 'B', 'E', 'F', 'C', 'G', 'D']`

Answer (score 2):

I suggest:

```
def extract_values_ordered_by_index(hash)
  Array.new(hash.values.map(&:length).max) do |i| 
    hash.values.map { |array| array[i] } 
  end.flatten.compact
end

hash = {a: [1, 2, 3], b: [4, 5], c: [6, 7, 8, 9]}
extract_values_ordered_by_index(hash)
#=> [1, 4, 6, 2, 5, 7, 3, 8, 9]

hash = {i: ['A'], ii: ['B', 'C', 'D'], iii: ['E'], iv: ['F', 'G']}
extract_values_ordered_by_index(hash)
#=> ["A", "B", "E", "F", "C", "G", "D"]
```

Another option is:

```
Array.new(hash.values.map(&:length).max)
     .zip(*hash.values).flatten.compact
```

Comment: Both work great! 
Just want to follow up that the second option is more efficient according to my benchmarks.

Answer (score 1):

```
def extract_values_ordered_by_index(hash)
  vals = hash.values.map(&:dup)
  finish = [[]] * vals.size
  loop.with_object([]) do |_,a|
    break a if vals == finish
    vals.each { |v| a << v.shift unless v.empty? }
  end
end
```

```
doit({ a: [1, 2, 3], b: [4, 5], c: [6, 7, 8, 9], d:[] })
  #=> [1, 4, 6, 2, 5, 7, 3, 8, 9]
```

```
doit({i: ['A'], ii: ['B', 'C', 'D'], iii: ['E'], iv: ['F', 'G']})
  #=> ["A", "B", "E", "F", "C", "G", "D"]
```

I first extract the hash's values to an array `vals`, removing any empty arrays in the process.

I then build an array `a` until `vals` is empty, at which time I break the loop, returning `a`.

At each iteration I shift the first element of each element of `vals` (an array, guaranteed to be non-empty) and append the shifted element of `a`, then remove all (now-empty) elements (arrays) of `vals`.

I do it this way in part to avoid using `Array#compact`, which I regard as an ugly--though admittedly useful--method.

---

If, however, `compact` is to be used, one could write

```
def extract_values_ordered_by_index(hash)
  vals = hash.values
  vals.map { |a| Array.new(vals.max_by(&:size).size) { |i| a[i] } }
      .transpose
      .flatten
      .compact
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's one way:

```rb
arr = {a: [1, 2, 3], b: [4, 5], c: [6, 7, 8, 9]}
arr.values.
    map{|ar| ar+Array.new(100)}.  # pad with nils
    inject{|a,ar| a.zip(ar)}.
    flatten.
    compact #=> [1, 4, 6, 2, 5, 7, 3, 8, 9]
```

it's pretty ugly though! In order to avoid the discarding of the elements of long arrays, pad them all with a lot of nils, and then discard the nils at the end with `compact`. You have to choose a padding length (I chose 100) that's "long enough" that elements are not discarded in the zip.

Answer (score -1):

Here's Other:

```
arr = {a: [1, 2, 3], b: [4, 5], c: [6, 7, 8, 9]}

arr.values.reduce(:+)

# => [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Comment: This doesn't return the values in the order the OP expects them.